# Delphi XE5 REST/Android Client "Session has expired"

Tags: android, delphi, rest, session-timeout, delphi-xe5

I have a `REST Server` with an `Android Client`, both on `Deplhi Xe5`

The android client succesfully connects with the Rest server.
In my server I have a `TDSHttpWebDispatcher` with `SessionTimeout`=1200000 (20 min)

So when the user in android doesn't use the app for more than 20 min, 
gets the "Session has expired" error when do a request to the REST server.

I already set the `PresserveSessionId=False` in the `DSRestConnection` in the Client app, so there is no sessiontimeout error, but it makes the app slower, because for every request to the REST server it creates a new session.

I wanna keep the `PresserveSessionId=True` for better performance, and when the session expires (after 20 min) catch the "Session has expired" error and request for a new session for the client

How can i achieve that?

Thanks

Sorry for my english!, hope it is readable

Answer (score 0):

There is an open QC report on this [here](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=116756). The obvious work around would be to create a `Try..Except` block on each call and on that specific exception request a new session.

Comment: Thanks, i solved it by setting the `TDSHttpWebDispatcher.SessionTimeout=0` on the Server side, so the session never expires